# is this possible dropdownlist with autocomplete and checkbox?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, checkbox, drop-down-menu

Briefly, i wanna use autocomplete and selectable checkboxes with dropdownlist if possible?

i'm using  [UFD](http://code.google.com/p/ufd) autocomplete plugin with my dropdownlists. And there's another plugin i googled [JQuery Dropdown Check List](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list).

Is there anyway to combine them or another idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see if [*this*](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is helpful it may not expose checkbox directly to the user but you can achieve the desired feature with demo. it is available in two flavors jquery and Prototype. 
**Selected and Disabled Support** or **<'optgroup'> Support** or **Multiple Select** demos may be of your interest i think **Multiple Select** does the same

hope this will suffice your needs....

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need checkboxes in autocomplete, i dont understand. In autocomplete you always search for one item. So you can search and enter something or click the link and add the found item to selected javascript array. I think this would be more usefull for you.

Comment: I think he thinks something like this: http://naukri-engineering.github.io/droope/#